# Unable to update an identity user in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to lockout a user in MVC 5 using ASP.NET Identity. I have followed suggestion from other SO posts (which all basically say the same thing) by doing the following:

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
var user = new ApplicationUser() {
    Id = form["AspNetUserID"],
    LockoutEnabled = true,
    LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(100)
};
IdentityResult result = await manager.UpdateAsync(user);
var context = store.Context;
context.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "SiteUsersAdmin");
```

I've stepped through the above code with a break point at the return line to find out the error and I keep getting either `Name cannot be null or empty` or `{Email/UserName} is already selected`

Who do I lock this account out or even unlock it in the future?

Comment: Try fetching the `user` from db instead of instantiating a new user.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I have been trying to do that since you posted your reply. There is nothing in the context menu for ApplicationDbContext that allows for updating, unless I am missing something. All the methods are for lambda expressions to retrieve data, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode....

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(form["AspNetUserID"]);
user.LockoutEnabled = true;
user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(100)};

var result = await manager.UpdateAsync(user);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //success
}
else
{
    //something went wrong
}
```